# Python: Scrapy and Reddit

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, reddit

I'm implementing a data pipeline for a chatbot. I'm crawling specific subreddits with scrapy to gather submission id's (not possible with praw - Python Reddit API Wrapper).

Further on I'm using praw to receive all the comments recursevly. Both of these implementations work already.

BUT, crawling subreddits gets denied by reddit after a few pages (depending on the speed of the get requests, ...).

I don't want to break any rules, but is there a proper scrapy configuration (DOWNLOAD_DELAY or other throttle mechanisms) which are within the reddit rules to gather such information?

My scrapy spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reddit'
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]

    def __init__(self, subreddit=None, pages=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RedditSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/%s/new/' % subreddit]
        self.pages = int(pages)
        self.page_count = 0

    def parse(self, response):

        # Extracting the content using css selectors
        titles = response.css('.title.may-blank::text').extract()
        # votes = response.css('.score.unvoted::text').extract()
        # times = response.css('time::attr(title)').extract()
        # comments = response.css('.comments::text').extract()
        submission_id = response.css('.title.may-blank').xpath('@data-outbound-url').extract()
        # submission_id = submission_id[24:33]

        # Give the extracted content row wise
        # for item in zip(titles, votes, times, comments, titles_full):
        for item in zip(titles, submission_id):
            # create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'submission_id': item[1][23:32]
                # 'vote': item[2],
                # 'created_at': item[3],
                # 'comments': item[4]
            }

            # yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info

        if (self.pages > 1) and (self.page_count < self.pages):
            self.page_count += 1
            next_page = response.css('span.next-button a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                print("next page ... " + next_page)
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

            if next_page is None:
                print("no more pages ... lol")
```

My spider configuration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for reddit_crawler_scrapy project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'reddit_crawler_scrapy'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['reddit_crawler_scrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'reddit_crawler_scrapy.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'reddit_crawler_scrapy university project m.reichart@hotmail.com'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'reddit_crawler_scrapy.middlewares.RedditCrawlerScrapySpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'reddit_crawler_scrapy.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'reddit_crawler_scrapy.pipelines.RedditCrawlerScrapyPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'

#Export as CSV Feed
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = "reddit.csv"


# RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = False

LOG_FILE='scrapy_log.txt'
```

I already set DOWNLOAD_DELAY to 5 seconds, this gets multiplied by a random number between 0.5 and 1.5 from the methode defined by RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY.
That equals in a get request/download something between 2.5sec and 7.5sec which is already quiet slow, but would do the job over some hours/days.

Still tough, after a few pages I dont receive a next page, and the last called page leads me to a submission provided by reddit with a link how to properly set up bots (imho in sarcastic tone - well played reddit).

Comment: what is missing in the api?

Comment: The API is only providing methods to get more or less random subreddits, or very specific queries. Seems much more like the methods are for applications which are presenting a specific topic, or work with "popular" subreddits or gold reddits and so on: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit/subreddits.html

Answer (score 1):

IMO working against reddits anti-crawl mechanisms will cost you too much time, I would not try to follow this road.

They *have* an API to get all the posts of one subreddit, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/top.json?sort=top gets the all the posts of in `/r/subreddit` as json format, it looks like the same content as you see on their websites.

Also, [their doc](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) suggest that you use oauth. Then they let you do 60 requests per minute. I would go this road instead. This is also a lot more safer than scraping as scraping will fall over whenever they change something in their HTML layout.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/top.json?sort=top and variations of it doesnt allow me to get like several pages of submissions within the /r/subreddit/new (all submissions beginning with the most recent submitted). I'll take a look into the API documentation, maybe I figure something out. praw is even listed within the official API documentation, but doesn't provide the requested methods :(

Comment: Meanwhile, if someone is well read on the reddit API documentation or knows the methods which provides me the requested data, pls let me know :)

Comment: did you look into https://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/new.json?sort=new ?

Comment: I did try several variations, the problem is that I can't get this format for page 1 of "new", page 2 of "new", ... of a specific subreddit. At least I'm not aware of, do you probably have any idea? Forgive me if the answer is obvious, I just started with processing and gathering of web data (and API's and any sort of these things) a few days ago.

Comment: FYI this also works for specific posts, just add `.json` to the URL.